# Techniques for a function to be Entire

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(u)$ be continuous and infinitely differentiable and let $\omega ,z \in \mathbb C$. Now consider the integral
$$\gamma(u)= |\omega| \int_{0}^{\infty} f(u) \bigg(\frac{\sin(zu + \theta)}{u} \bigg)\;du ,$$
where $\theta = arg(\omega)$. 
**Is there a technique for this function to be entire? Or there's nothing we can do here due to $\sin(zu+\theta)$.** 
 
 Any help or paper's that would somehow related would be so much appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you considered differentiation under the integral sign ?

Comment: This resembles laplace transforms, so by analogue …

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I haven't try that approach.

Comment: you need $f$ to decrease faster than any exponential $e^{uR}$, so $f$ of compact support or something like $f(u)=e^{-e^{u}}, e^{-u^2}$ etc works; also if $\theta \ne 0, \pi$ you need $f(u)/u$ to be integrable at $0$ so in that case maybe something like $f(u)=u^ne^{-e^{u}}, n \geq 1$

Comment: Thank you so much, @Conrad. Could you please provide a link or recommend.